# Is there a tool that can take partition table information and partition another based on it?

Tags: scripting, partition, parted, partition-table

Is there a tool that can read the partitioning information of a disk and partition another disk based on that information?

I don't know whether parted for instance can partition a disk based on a script, or whether there is a tool that can read a partition table and create a script that parted might be able to use, but I am interested in something like that if it exists.

Comment: so we're trying to get the same sized partitions, same types, but without the content of them?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes

Comment: `parted` should do it.  it can print out partitions in any unit you want, and then more invocations of parted would recreate it step by step.

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably late, but anyway.. Copying partition table from sda to sdb:

Copy mbr and partition table of sda to files:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=sda.mbr count=1 bs=512
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.sf
```

Copy it from files to another drive (here sdb):

```
dd if=sda.mbr of=/dev/sdb
sfdisk /dev/sdb < sda.sf
```

If you don't need mbr skip the dd lines.